# Align elements to the bottom of the row in responsive table-like layout

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, grid, css-tables

I have the following Group component which, depending on the viewport size, will display 2 or 3 columns:

```js
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var group = document.getElementById('group');

toggleBtn.onclick = function(e) {
 if (toggleBtn.innerText === 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT') {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group big';
  }
  else {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group small';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
}

.group::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.group.small .item {
  width: 50%;
}

.group.big .item {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  clear: both;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) .cell {
  background: yellow;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) .cell {
  background: cyan;
}

label {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group" class="group big">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input1">Input 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input2">Input 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input3">Input 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input4">Input 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input5">Input 5 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input5" id="input5" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input6">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input6" id="input6" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input7">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input7" id="input7" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="toggle">FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT</button>
```

You can click on the button to change from the 2-columns to the 3-columns version.

The problem is that elements on the same row should be aligned to the bottom of it instead than to the top, so that all the inputs are aligned to the bottom, whatever the size of the label is.

I know that can be done with using JS, but I would like to know if there's any solution that solve the problem without it that works in IE10+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inline block, instead of float.

```
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```js
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var group = document.getElementById('group');

toggleBtn.onclick = function(e) {
 if (toggleBtn.innerText === 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT') {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group big';
  }
  else {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group small';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
}

.group::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  /*float: left;*/
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  display: inline-block; /*added*/
  vertical-align: bottom;  /*added*/
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font size*/
}

.group.small .item {
  width: 50%;
}

.group.big .item {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  clear: both;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) .cell {
  background: yellow;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) .cell {
  background: cyan;
}

label {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group" class="group big">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input1">Input 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input2">Input 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input3">Input 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input4">Input 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input5">Input 5 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input5" id="input5" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input6">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input6" id="input6" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input7">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input7" id="input7" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="toggle">FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT</button>
```

Or using CSS3 flexbox.

```
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```js
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var group = document.getElementById('group');

toggleBtn.onclick = function(e) {
 if (toggleBtn.innerText === 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT') {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group big';
  }
  else {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group small';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  display: flex; /*added*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*added*/
  align-items: flex-end; /*added*/
}

.group::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; */
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.group.small .item {
  width: 50%;
}

.group.big .item {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  clear: both;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) .cell {
  background: yellow;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) .cell {
  background: cyan;
}

label {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group" class="group big">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input1">Input 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input2">Input 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input3">Input 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input4">Input 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input5">Input 5 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input5" id="input5" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input6">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input6" id="input6" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input7">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input7" id="input7" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="toggle">FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways:

flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

or if you experiment with more rich html structure, you can archieve it by vertical-align:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

If I mistaken your issue, please comment my post.

For js example...

```
document.getElementById("something").style.verticalalign = "top"
```

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block instead float would allow to use vertical-align.

```js
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var group = document.getElementById('group');

toggleBtn.onclick = function(e) {
 if (toggleBtn.innerText === 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT') {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group big';
  }
  else {
   toggleBtn.innerText = 'FAKE BIG VIEWPORT';
   group.className = 'group small';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
}

.group::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.group.small .item {
  width: 50%;
}

.group.big .item {
  width: 31%;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  clear: both;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n),
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n+1) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n+1) .cell {
  background: yellow;
}

.group.small .item:nth-child(2n) .cell,
.group.big .item:nth-child(3n) .cell {
  background: cyan;
}

label {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group" class="group big">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input1">Input 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input2">Input 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input3">Input 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input4">Input 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input5">Input 5 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input5" id="input5" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input6">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input6" id="input6" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="input7">Input 6 bla bla bla bla bla bla</label>
      <input type="text" name="input7" id="input7" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="toggle">FAKE SMALL VIEWPORT</button>
```